# Demystifying Font Appearance on Linux : The Proper Way

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, debian

Can someone enlighten me on the way font appearance (hinting, antialiasing) works? As far as I understand,

1. There is .fonts.conf
2. There are individual font settings for Gnome, XFCE and KDE (or do they just modify .fonts.conf; or else where do they keep their font configurations?) For XFCE, it is in ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml for example.
3. Then there are .Xresources and libXFT.
4. Then there is some info regarding BCI which is not enabled by default, however this seems rather obsolete as far as I understand.
5. Finally, there is the issue of a DPI setting, which I can specify in Xorg, or in each WM.

I am confused as to which setting is used when. To add more confusion, some terminal programs have an option to antialias fonts.

It seems that .fonts.conf is the best of these options; but still with a .fonts.conf the appearance seems to differ under different WMs.

I am running Debian and Ubuntu btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- /etc/fonts hold Xft settings, while
  .fonts.conf is a per-user override of
  /etc/fonts/*
- DEs set their settings using X
  settings daemon (there are several of
  them, one in each DE, and also
  several standalone for  use with
  lightweight WMs)
- applications get settings either from
  Xft directly (/etc/fonts), or from X
  settings daemon if it is active.
- some applications (e.g. Google
  Chrome) only get settings from X
  settings daemon. so the only way to
  get proper fonts in Chrome running
  under lightweight WM is to run some
  sort of xsettingsd
- gtk and qt apps treat some of Xft
  settings differently, so it can be
  tricky to create fonts.conf that
  works in the same way in Qt and GTK.

and here's what i think, but didn't really check:

- GDK/Pango uses Xft with its default
  settings, either from fonts.conf or X
  settings.
- Qt adds extra tweaks to fonts.conf
  settings, which breaks some of the
  settings.
- Cairo seems to respect xft settings,
  but rendering looks slightly
  differently compared to Pango.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm not exactly sure how much of the below is truth, but it is how I understand these things. Comment/edit/correct if you like.*

- `/etc/fonts/local.conf`, `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` and `~/.fonts.conf` are for `freetype2`. They handle font substitution, per-font settings, all that stuff, and they apply for FreeType no matter where it is used.
- `Xft` X resources only apply when FreeType is used in X through libxft. They override `fontconfig` settings.
- GNOME font smoothing settings are just passed to Xft when `gnome-settings-manager` is started. They override settings specified in X resources. Probably the same in KDE and Xfce.
- Terminal emulators using libxft, like any other program, can tell it to use specific settings (such as 'disable antialiasing'), probably per-widget or something. (In Windows, programs can opt out of ClearType too.)
- WM means "window manager". Window managers only care about managing windows, I haven't seen one that would touch my font settings. (Try starting `metacity`, `xfwm4`, `compiz` directly, you should see no difference in font rendering.)